# multipart/form-data webclient c#

Tags: c#, rest, post, webclient, multipart

I need to send a request [of this type](http://developers.redu.com.br/resources/lecture.html):

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: OAuth AJOBibdmecfKxOpEeRWbdmVVCGujGRU3JKA0jyQM' \
  -F 'lecture\[media\]=@video.avi;type=video/mpeg' \
  -F 'lecture\[name\]=My lecture' \
  -F 'lecture\[type\]=Media' \
  http://www.redu.com.br/api/subjects/117/lectures -vv
```

I want to use the `WebClient` class in C# to make a multipart POST request for sending JSON + file to be loaded, but do not know how I can do this, can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a `WebClient` implementation, but there are most definitely `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse` ones, [such as this one here](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c).

Comment: @IchabodClay There is a WebClient http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx :D :D :D :D but I'm sure your contribution was very important :D :D :D :D Thanks a lot.